# Does it leave configuration files if I do install when I get the message The following packages have been kept back:

Tags: ubuntu, apt

In multiple questions that handle the question: how to resolve `The following packages have been kept back:` message suggest to use `sudo apt-get install package-name` or `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` The latter didn't work for me.

Now the thing that has me nervous is that "things need to be removed to perform this upgrade" that shimmers through all the answers.

This is on a production server and I can't afford long downtimes. The packages that need upgrading are `mariadb-client`  and `mariadb-server` so i'm hesistant to just blast along and possibly leave a lot of people fiddling their thumbs if stuff goes south.

That's why I'd like to know if the configuration files and databases are kept as they are if I do `sudo apt-get install mariadb-server`

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS